# Как привязать событие к определенному  времени ролика?

Tags: javascript

Такой вопрос!
Возможно ли привязать событие (ну, например, появление текста в блоке) к определенной минуте ролика с ютуб? например, когда видеопросмотр дойдет до 2-й минуты, начнет ниже плеера появляться текст.

Comment: @cevil_cevil, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

У элемента `video` есть событие [`timeupdate`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_timeupdate.asp), вы можете завязаться на него. Только не пишите слишком тяжёлый код в обработчике, событие вызывается очень часто. Попробуйте ограничить срабатывание обработчика одним разом в секунду.

Comment: Или просто сделать условие: 
`if (video.currentTime > 120) {
// какой-то нужный action
}`

Comment: ...и action будет выполнаться каждые несколько миллисекунд начиная со второй минуты видео. Сверху тоже стоит ограничить.

Comment: @fori1ton, либо сделать так, чтобы условие выполнялось 1 раз, думаю, что функцию с условием нужно засовывать в timeupdate и при выполнении условия прекращать выполнение этих событий.